# Laravel/VueJs Sanctum CSRF mismatch when deployed

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

Can't seem to work out why I keep getting CSRF token mismatch with my deployed app. On local using valet it's working fine.

The backend and frontend are on 2 different servers but they share the same subdomain so surely this should work?

My local .env contains the following:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.rss.test
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=front.rss.test:3001
```

My live .env contains the following:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.dally.tech
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=rss.dally.tech
```

The API is sat on the domain:

```
rss-api.dally.tech
```

Really confused why this isn't working.